# How to use Laravel custom package, called laravel-users?

Tags: laravel

I made a new Laravel 5.8 project and run the

```
php artisan make:auth
```

and finished DataBase setup/connection. Now I followed the instructions from "https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-users". After publishing it (4 in instructions), I run "php artisan serve" but it still shows the standard Laravel Welcome with login/register option from Auth. What more files do I need to edit/copy to get the "laravel-users" running/showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already run the `make:auth` command. The standard views are already in place (check `resources/views/auth`).

Either manually copy the correct views and assets from the Laravel-Users package, or discard all the auth scaffolding and run the `make:auth` command again with the package already installed.

Comment: I ran the make:auth again and its like the Laravel-Users does not exists at all. Is there an easier way than just a manual copy?

Comment: Then you've either skipped an instruction, or the instructions are invalid. I'd take this to their support/issues board if you're sure you've followed the installation protocol. Might take ages for somebody to stumble upon your question here on SO.